# NSIS : Delete files from Hidden folder (from start menu)

Tags: nsis

I have written code script for uninstall of my application, somehow uninstall.exe is getting deleted. so script is not able to uninstall product . Now I want to write a script to delete folders directly from directory, 
From 
1. Installation Directory 
2. Start Menu

I can delete it from Installation Directory , but as start Menu is inside ProgramData , and Program data folder is hidden. I am not able to delete it by nsis, please suggest the efficient approach.

Description :

-When I install new version of application ,it'll automatically uninstall previous installed location (just running uninstall.exe).
-Sometimes some how uninstall.exe get deleted , so while installing new version , user needs to delete application mannually from installed location and from  StartMenu (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\$application)

I am thinking to remove these directoryy from nsis script.
But C:\ProgramData is hidden so i am not able to delete it by script,

Is there  any possible way.

Comment: Sounds unlikely, please post example code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hi @Anders, I have updated scenario

Comment: NSIS does not care if a folder is hidden. I can't help you without code showing how delete does not work. Windows and NSIS version information would be useful as well.